# About loading dynamic library in container

Tags: linux, docker, dll, containers

Frankly speaking, I'm foreigner in container.

However I have some questions about loading libraries during runtime in container.

I will explain with simple example.

If program `A` running in a container, loads `alpha` library(.so) dynamically (in runtime) using something like `dlopen`. Then the library will be loaded in memory.

If I run another container which runs program `A`, it will load `alpha` library again.

In this case, is `alpha` library loads twice or two containers share the library(`alpha`)?

How can I check this out??

Please give me some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably possible they will share pages at a very low level, if both containers are built from the same image, but there's almost no way to observe this.  Why does it matter; can you provide some application code that will behave differently one way or the other?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for comment, hmm.. I want to implement memory optimization between containers, because I have to use large size shared library. Therefore if it is possible to prove that  we can share memory, I can make some design easily.

Answer (score 0):

By loaded I assume libraries that are loaded to RAM.

Yes, it should be loaded again as each container is a logically separate execution unit, access to loaded libraries in one container will not be available to any other container.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then is there any way to share library in memory with other container?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The whole point behind containers is the separation of  resources

Comment: Then if I want to proove that, is there any way to make some experiments? As I thought, just dynamically load library in several containers and watch the increment of memory.

Comment: You could try and tweak a library, source code, maybe change functionality in one container and see if that is reflected in the other container as well.

Comment: In that way, I can figure it out whether share or not in memory. I'll try it. Thanks.